# Bug with the profile edit save buttons

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, responsive-design

The 2 buttons seem too close to each other. Can this be fixed?

[image]

To get this you need to have an account on any site that you have not edited your profile before. So if you have customized your account on Meta but not on ELL, going to ELL to change it for the first time gives you a single button. Click the "customize your profile just on this community" under the single button to get the duo stacked buttons.

I entered the page by pressing settings, edit profile in the navigation bar then "customize your profile just on this community". I am on Chrome (version 103.0.5060.71) for Android, resolution 2220×1080 on mobile.

Comment: [Not repro on Chrome 103, Pixel 3a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvXeQ.png).